# Chrome don't release memory after refresh a page when I open dev tool in v86

Tags: google-chrome, memory-leaks

**Performance monitor snapshot**

[image: 1]

All metrics in above snapshot keep climbing if i refresh any website while opening dev tool.
It's quite annoying while I am developing a web app with hot reloading.

**env:**

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.80 Safari/537.36

Comment: Welcome, What is your question or expectation?

Comment: I expect chrome  release those useless documents in some ways.It runs out of my memory  if i refresh too much. @Gi1ber7